# How to login GAE app using Postman

Tags: google-app-engine, postman

We have an app that fetches data through REST API after being authenticated in the browser with this:

[image]

In what way can this process be done through pure REST access using Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the REST API provides a login call that stores information in a session (using a cookie), then you can call that first.  After that, Postman will send the cookie with every request, maintaining the session.